# Twitter Screen Name returning a null in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, parse-platform

Logging in via Twitter and trying to get the Users screen name. The screen name produces a null value each time. Any ideas?

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    [PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
            return;
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            twitterScreenName = [PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName;
            NSLog(@"%@",[PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName);
            NSString * requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=%@", twitterScreenName ];

                                        NSURL *verify = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
                                        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:verify];
                                        [[PFTwitterUtils twitter] signRequest:request];

                                        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                NSError *error;
                NSDictionary* result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                if (!error) {

                   user.username =twitterScreenName;
                   user[@"name"]= result[@"name"];
                    user[@"profileDescription"] = result[@"description"];
                  user[@"imageURL"] = [result[@"profile_image_url_https"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_normal" withString:@"_bigger"];
                    [user saveEventually];
                }
            }];
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"username" sender: self];

        }
```

Comment: I'll answer below, but if you're using logInWithBlock, you shouldn't be using the first line PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser] because no one is logged in yet so there is no current user!

Comment: @spogebob92 were you able to solve it? I got same problem and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I do it:

```
[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if ([PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) {
        NSURL *info = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:info];
        [[PFTwitterUtils twitter] signRequest:request];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            if (!!data) {
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
                NSString *userName = dict[@"screen_name"];
                userName = [userName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Twitter:" withString:@""];

                PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
                user[@"Twitter"] = userName;
                [user saveEventually];
            } else {
              //uh oh, no twitter response
            }
        }];
    } else {
        //uh oh, failed login
    }
}];
```

Comment: With that code i get this error: 

Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(BOOL, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'PFUserResultBlock' (aka 'void (^)(PFUser *__strong, NSError *__strong)')

Comment: oh oops, it should be [PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

}];

My bad on that one.

Comment: Its really strange, sometimes it manages to grab the data, other times it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: when does it and when doesn't it? randomly?

Comment: It requires me to login twice before I am able to get the screen name.

Comment: This solution still works for me with the most updated version of Parse. You must have something set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring this in the Twitter portal.  It will give you options for which permissions your app has (meaning you might have to enable returning a username manually from within Twitter's dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)TWloginPress:(id)sender {
    [activityview setHidden:NO];
    [activityview startAnimating];
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
     (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
         if (session) {
              [self signupUser:session.userName email:nil loggedinvia:@"TWITTER"];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"There was some problem with signing you with twitter. Please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
         }
     }];
}
```