# Twitter Login Parse iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, parse-platform

I'm building an Twitter iOS login. When trying to get the screen name of a new user, on the first login, it doesn't get the screen name, on the second log in it does. How can I make it so that I can get the screen name on the first log in?

Here is the code I am using:

```
[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
        return;
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in with Twitter!");

        NSLog(@"%@", [PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"hasUsername" sender: self];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User logged in with Twitter!");
       NSLog(@"%@", [PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"hasUsername" sender: self];
    }     
}];
```

The NSLog functions just return a null value on the first login.

Comment: Here is an answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30409439/277021

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use when using Twitter login and Parse:

```
[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if ([PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) {
        NSURL *info = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:info];
        [[PFTwitterUtils twitter] signRequest:request];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            if (!!data) {
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
                NSString *userName = dict[@"screen_name"];
                userName = [userName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Twitter:" withString:@""];

                PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
                user[@"Twitter"] = userName;
                [user saveEventually];
            } else {
                //uh oh, no twitter response
            }
        }];
    } else {
        //uh oh, failed login
    }
}];
```

Copied from my other answer at: [Twitter Screen Name returning a null in Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581050/twitter-screen-name-returning-a-null-in-parse/29581553?noredirect=1#comment47328487_29581553)

Comment: That was me in the previous thread. This only grabs the screen name on the second log in.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, adding a Twitter account to the iOS simulator fixed it for me. You can do this by going to Settings -> Twitter and from there create or sign up.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName but do it after the [PFTwitterUtils loginWithBlock... ] block. Before then it's not setup, which is why you have to run it twice. So:

```
[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

    some stuff

    }     
}];
NSLog(@"%@", [PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName);
```

You can still load a welcome screen on user.isNew and stuff like that, but loading the screenname, ID, etc, of the [PFTwitterUtils twitter] won't work until the block has ended.