# PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock always returns nil for userId

Tags: ios, object, twitter, parse-platform

The logInWithBlock method of PFTwitterUtils always returns userId as nil. 
Any idea why this might be happening?

I am using parse.com version: 1.7.2

```
[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
            return;
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in with Twitter!");

            if([PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]){
                NSLog(@"userID %@", [PFTwitterUtils twitter].userId);
            }

        //...

        } else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in with Twitter!");
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason userId is nil is because this user has been already logged in on the device.
This might happen if you are testing a lot on your device and forget to do a logout.

If you logout before you attempt to login again it will be fine.

So here is an example for testing:

```
[PFUser logOut];

[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
            return;
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in with Twitter!");

            if([PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]){
                NSLog(@"userID %@", [PFTwitterUtils twitter].userId);
            }

        //...

        } else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in with Twitter!");
        }
    }];
```